# Axios returns [Error: Network Error] only on Android. Works fine in iOS

Tags: android, react-native, axios

The below webservice call works fine on iOS, but goes to the catch block and returns error when run on Android.

```
let dataToSend = {username: 'someUsername' ,password: 'somePassword'};
axios.post('https://some-domain.com:11443/websrc/login',dataToSend,{
    headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
})
.then (function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

**Output in Android**

```
[Error: Network Error]
```

Comment: are you making a localhost call?

Comment: No. This is a domain available on public network.

Comment: I don't know anything about React Native or Axios, but Android apps written in Java that use internet need to have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in `android-manifest.xml`. It wouldn't surprise me if React Native behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same problem. In my case, all API requests works fine when my android app is linked to localhost (http) or our production server (https), but return a Network Error when my app is linked to our staging server (https too). This is really strange and cannot understand why..

Comment: Answer doesn't answer the question asked. It could be under comments instead of answer.