# VueJS page: Throws "Network error" only from mobile browser, works fine from laptop

Tags: android, vue.js, google-chrome, axios

A page that I developed using Vuejs works fine through a laptop browser (Firefox, Chrome and Edge) but when attempted through Chrome or Firefox browser on mobile, the axios call throws a "Network error". I checked settings, both browsers have javascript enabled. I am not sure what code/settings to paste here. I would appreciate it very much if you could help me fix this issue, shall share any settings/configuration that you might need to help fix this. Thanks for your help.

This is one such axios call that fails on mobile but works on laptop

```
var urltocall = BASEURL + "sendotp";
var inputJson = `{"${Message.PARAM_USERNAME}": "${this.username}"}`;

axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: urltocall,
    data: inputJson,
    config: {
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:1337',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    }
})
    .then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
.catch(function (error) {
    alert(error);
});
```

I found this query posted a month ago, a variation of the problem I am facing.
[Axios returns [Error: Network Error] only on Android. Works fine in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179479/axios-returns-error-network-error-only-on-android-works-fine-in-ios)

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the problem with Axios alone, without Vue. The error could be anything. It's specific to API that you call and request details. Unless you can provide a way to reproduce the problem, I don't see how it could be solved.

Comment: But the same call works fine on laptop browser.

Comment: does your website has any certificates to be downloaded by browser ? Could you provide full log trace you are getting ?

Comment: The SSL certificate is recognised by mobile Chrome, it says "connection is secure". How do I get the log trace in mobile Chrome ? I searched in the net but could not find any option so far

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - this makes no sense on client side, it's a server that should specify headers. Does this mean that you do requests to local server? Then the problem is specific to this. It could be anything regarding network transport that is specific to your device and the way it works with this specific server, not Android in general.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: The request is to a public URL, not a local server. Yes, I agree that the CORS header makes no sense in the client but I don't think that is causing this issue. I find it tough to debug as it is working when called from laptop browser

Comment: Found the issue - the mobile browsers were not recognising the SSL certificate used for the URL that was being called via axios. When I switched the certificate to another CA, it worked from mobile browser too.

Comment: How did you figure that out? I'm having the same issue where I can't access my public API on mobile devices (new API with new SSL Cert), anything would help!